# Tweener on start AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, tweener

```
for (var i:int=cardCount; i < numberOfCardsToDispatch;i++){

            Tweener.addTween(packArray[i], {x:packPosX - dealXPos, time:.4, delay:dealDelay, transition:"easeOutExpo", onStart:function(){packArray[i].visible = true;}});


        }
```

I'm looping through my array, packArray[i] refers to a sprite. I want it so that as soon as the Tween starts the sprite is visible.

The above code does not tween the sprite, just freezes it, as soon as I take onStart out, it works. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tweener* is no longer maintain. You should try *[TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/)*.

> Tweener was maintained from june 2005 to june 2009. While it still works, it's not being maintained anymore [...]

With *Tweener*:

```
Tweener.addTween(packArray[i], {
    time: .4,
    delay: dealDelay,
    x: packPosX - dealXPos,
    ease: "easeOutExpo",
    onStart: function():void { this.visible = true; } // You should use this
});
```

With *TweenMax*:

```
TweenMax.to(packArray[i], .4, {
    delay: dealDelay,
    x: packPosX - dealXPos, // Or "-100" if you want to move to the left to 100px
    ease: Expo.easeOut,
    onStart: function():void { packArray[i].visible = true; }
});
```